# UIAlertController makes the app unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

This is the code I am using for displaying and handling `UIAlertController` in actionSheet style.

```
actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheetController.view.tintColor = TGProjectHandler.getAppThemeColor()
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Just dismiss the action sheet
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let inviteMemberAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Invite member", style: .default) { action -> Void in
            let newActivityInviteTableController = NewActivityInviteTableViewController()
            newActivityInviteTableController.invite_type = 1
            newActivityInviteTableController.activity = self.activity
            self.invitation_type = 1
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newActivityInviteTableController)
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            newActivityInviteTableController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissPopover))
            newActivityInviteTableController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: newActivityInviteTableController.self, action: #selector(newActivityInviteTableController.sendInviteRequest))
            if (!(newActivityInviteTableController == nil))
            {
                self.navigationController!.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(inviteMemberAction)
        let inviteChildAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Invite child", style: .default)
        { action -> Void in

            let newActivityInviteChildTableController = NewActivityInviteChildTableViewController()
            self.invitation_type = 2
            newActivityInviteChildTableController.activity = self.activity
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newActivityInviteChildTableController)
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
            navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            newActivityInviteChildTableController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissPopover))

            newActivityInviteChildTableController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: newActivityInviteChildTableController.self, action: #selector(newActivityInviteChildTableController.sendInviteRequest))
            if (!(newActivityInviteChildTableController == nil))
            {
                self.navigationController!.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }

        actionSheetController.addAction(inviteChildAction)
        self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Though random, but sometimes it make the app unresponsive. If I display/dismiss the **actionSheetController** for a couple of times, the **actionSheetController** remains on the screen and then app becomes unresponsive to touch.

Comment: You are presenting the AlertController, so you should dismiss it, But I can see you are using popViewController!!!!
hope this helps

Comment: @Janmenjaya `UIAlertController` dismisses itself when an action is selected

Comment: @Nitish I can't see any issue with this code.  I suggest you use the time profiler instrument to analyse your app performance